# AJAX multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below code and it is acting in a way that I dont understand.  The  purpose seems pretty straightforward to me, if the first ajax call is successful, then get the `loggedInUser` from another ajax GET call and reload the page to the link created.  My Code looks like

```
function getLoggedInUser() {    
  var username = "";    
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/getLoggedInUser',
    data: [],
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
      alert("a " + username);
      username = response.username;
      alert("b " +username);
      var link = "/_marshall/rssadd/";
      link = link+username;
      alert("c " + link);

    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    //alert("Please Try Again, we had an internal error!");
      alert(err.message);
      args['error'] = "1";
    }
  });

  alert("d " + username);
  return username;
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{    
  $("#rssCreateSubmit").click(function(event) {    
    var rssInfo = {}    
    rssInfo["title"] = $("#rssCreateTitle").val();
    rssInfo["category"] = $("#rssCreateCategory").val();
    rssInfo["copyright"] = $("#rssCreateCopyright").val();
    rssInfo["description"] = $("#rssCreateDescription").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/createRSS',
      data: rssInfo,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response)
      {
        var loggedInUser = getLoggedInUser();
        alert("e " + loggedInUser);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error)
      {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      //alert("Please Try Again, we had an internal error!");
      alert(err.message);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

The alerts print out in this order, which I do not understand.  I think it has something to do with ajax being asynchronous, but I am not too sure what that means and I still feel like this code should work.  Thanks.

```
"d "
"e "
"a "
"b value"
"c /_marshall/rssadd/value"
```

And the html link in changes to the below instead of rerouting:

```
http://www.bugbounty.design/_marshall/rsscreate/testMarshall1?rssCreateCategory=&InputEmail=
```

Comment: is this your code or someone elses code, you seem unsure about this

Comment: I see the problem. $.ajax is **asynchronous**, so returning username like you do wont work. You either need to use a callback method or promises, and recode your code to account for the fact that you have an asynchronous call in there

Comment: @JaromandaX I HATE javascript and spent the last 3 hours trying to figure this out.  Its all my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logic around a bit and you get this

```
function getLoggedInUser() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/api/getLoggedInUser',
        data: [],
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            //alert("Please Try Again, we had an internal error!");
            alert(err.message);
            args['error'] = "1";
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rssCreateSubmit").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/createRSS',
            data: rssInfo,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                getLoggedInUser().then(function(response) {
                    alert("a " + username);
                    username = response.username;
                    alert("b " + username);
                    var link = "/_marshall/rssadd/";
                    link = link + username;
                    alert("c " + link);
                })
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                //alert("Please Try Again, we had an internal error!");
                alert(err.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are taken out of the main execution thread. This is why 'd' and 'e' are printed first, since they are not in an ajax call.

I found this video really helpful for understanding ajax 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: after your alert('c' + link), add,
alert('d' + username);
alert('e' + username);